# Making Point Z feature class out of Point feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, geometry-conversion

I have a point shapefile where i need to transfer the records into a geodatabase feature class that is Point Z.  I have found a number of processes to go the other way, removing Z value and make it a simple point, but I want to go the other way.  I know I do not have Z values so wondering if this is possible and the points would just get a Z value of 0, or if Arcmap will just continue to give me errors when I try to convert.  I tried enabling Z values in the geoprocessing environment menu and then did a Feature Class to Feature Class geoprocess, but it created the new feature class without Z values still.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

sigh.... turned out to be an arcmap bug that a restart fixed.  once i restarted, the feature class to feature class geoprocess with Environment Z values enabled worked and the points came out as Point Z